# AVR32DA28 watchdog randomly resets

Tags: c, avr, watchdog

I am trying to work with **Watchdog System Reset Mode**.
The problem is, it is running good at the start of the mcu but after running for any random period of time it reset the mcu even if i am resetting the counter before the counter overflow. The System reset is occurring randomly. I have tried configuring the watchdog  by atmel start, by manual configuration and importing the avr/wdt.h library also but the result is still same. My Mcu is running on internal 12Mhz Clock.
for your better understand i am providing all the methods i have tried below please give your valuable time to read this and share your opinion on this.

Atmel Start import

```
int8_t WDT_0_init()
{

ccp_write_io((void *)&(WDT.CTRLA),
             WDT_PERIOD_1KCLK_gc /* 1K cycles (1.0s) */
                 | WDT_WINDOW_OFF_gc /* Off */);

return 0;
}
```

Library import

```
int main(void)
{
wdt_disable();
atmel_start_init();
wdt_enable(WDTO_1S);
sei();

while (1) {
wdt_reset();
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Do you have any ISRs that might be taking longer than that?

Comment: i extremely sorry for being late, yes i have five interrupts running parallel with this, Two **TIMER INTERRUPT**, One **USART** receive complete interrupt, one **ZCD** and An **ADC** interrupt. How do i tackle with this any suggestion from you will be highly appreciable.